# ng-model is not working on dynamically created html form in angularjs 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

`ng-model` was working fine before i dynamically added html form using `ng-bind-html` but now its not working in `AngularJS 1.5.3`.

html

```
 <div ng-bind-html="formHtml">
  </div>     
  <div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button ng-click="submit()" class="button button-full button-positive" style="background-color:#853a96;">
        Send Feedback
      </button>
   </div>
```

Controller

```
.controller('feedbackCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $location, $http, $sce) {    

$scope.formData = {};

 $window.onload = function () {  
// fetchting the form from server    
var testing = "<form><input type='text' name='clientName' value='g' ng-model='formData.clientName'></form>";
$scope.formHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(testing);
};

$scope.skip = function () {

$location.path("/app");
}

$scope.submit = function () { 

var Payload = {
  GcmId: window.global.GCM_TOKEN,
  FeedbackJson: {
    name: $scope.formData.clientName,
    comments: $scope.formData.clientComment
  }
// 
// post request to upload values 
};
};
});
```

when I do `console.log($scope.formData.clientName)` of input values I get `undefined`. Please help, thanks.